Proof of the Properties of the Additive Inverse in a Field
I'm working through Sheldon Axler's Supplement for Measure, Integration, & Real Analysis (this link includes the required Creative Commons copywrite link at the end of the document; no changes were made). I'm going to be asking the community here for feedback on these proofs since I'm not very good at writing proofs yet.
Exercise A, 1: Prove 0.3. (p. 11)
0.3 properties of the additive inverse in a field (p. 3)
Suppose $\textbf{F}$ is a field. Then
(a) for each $a\in\textbf{F}$, the additive inverse of $a$ is unique (thus the notation $-a$ makes sense);
(b) $-(-a) = a$ for each $a\in\textbf{F}$;
(c) $(-1)a = -a$ for each $a\in\textbf{F}$.
My Proof:
(a) Let $b\in\textbf{F}$ be the additive inverse of $a$. By way of contradiction, temporarily assume that $c\in\textbf{F}$ such that $c\neq b$ is also the additive inverse of $a$. By the definition of the additive inverse, $a+c=0$ and $a+b=0$, which implies that $a+c=a+b$, which further implies that $c=b$. This contradicts our given assumption that $c\neq b$. Therefore, for each $a\in\textbf{F}$, the additive inverse of $a$ is unique.
(b) Let $b$ be the additive inverse of $a$ so that $a+b=0$. This implies that $-b=a$ and that $-a=b$. By substitution, $-(-a)=a$.
(c) $(-1)a=(-1)(a)=-1a=-a$. $\blacksquare$
Feedback Requested
(1) Since my background is in the humanities, I'm used to writing paragraphs, which is why I'm gravitating toward writing paragraph proofs. How is my writing? Should I make it more concise and if so, how?
(2) How is my mathematical reasoning? My suspicion is that (c) is wrong. If my reasoning is wrong, can you explain exactly where it is wrong? I saw an elegant proof of (c) by gf255, where he/she states: $a+(−1)a=1a+(−1)a=(1+−1)a=0a=0$.
(3) This is my first post. How is my post? Should I attribute or cite things differently? Should I break down each individual section (i.e., (a), (b), and (c)) into its own post, or is it okay if I group them together?
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As for $(a)$, usually there is no need to suppose by way of contradiction that a different inverse exists: you may take two inverses $b, c \in\textbf{F} $ and prove $b=c$, which is what you actually did

The statement of $(c)$ is that the additive inverse of the multiplicative identity multiplied by $a$ is the additive inverse of $a$. I think that removing the parentheses in your proof is incorrect: you said $(-1)(a)=-(1)(a)$, but you still have to prove that
